# Vue resource interceptor to refresh JWT token

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I am trying to write a vue-resource interceptor that refreshes the JWT access token, when it has expired.  I assume that I need to have a post-request callback that checks for token expiration error (`status == 401` in my case), and then calls the refresh endpoint and re-tries the initial request.

With the code below, the only problem I face is that the `next()` call after refreshing the token never happens, even though the refresh executes fine and new tokens are saved to the `localStorage`.

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function (request, next) {

    if (!request.headers.has('Authorization') && window.localStorage.access_token) {
        request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${window.localStorage.access_token}`);
    }

    next(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 401) {
            const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

            Vue.http.post('/api/v4/auth/refresh', null, {
                headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${refreshToken}`}
            }).then((response) => {
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.accessToken);
                localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refreshToken);
            }).then(() => {
                next();
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the chaining of callbacks is not quite right. The second call to next should happen when the first call returns a promise, and should not depend on the logic applied to resolve the first promise, only on successful resolution of that promise.

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function (request, next) {

  if (!request.headers.has('Authorization') && window.localStorage.access_token) {
    request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${window.localStorage.access_token}`);
  }

  next(function (response) {
    if (response.status === 401) {
        const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

        return Vue.http.post('/api/v4/auth/refresh', null, {
            headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${refreshToken}`}
        }).then((response) => {
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.accessToken);
            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refreshToken);
        })
    }
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  }).then(() => {
     next(); // This is called whenever the first callback returns a promise
  });
})
```

Comment: When applying your suggested changes I get a `TypeError: next(...).then is not a function.` Not sure what exactly is wrong? My guess is that when `response.status` there is no `Promise` to attach `then` to ? Even if this works, I still have a doubt that simply calling `next()` for the second time won't work. I am not sure if and how the `response` object will be modified in the second `next()` call.

Comment: My bad. The first call should resolve the promise if the status is 200. I've edited my answer. On the last point, why should the response be modified on the second call to next()?

Comment: I don't think that the value from `return Promise.resolve(...)` neither `return Vue.http.post` is ever propagated up the `next()` stack. Meaning that my interceptor calls `next()` and passes down a function to be executed on the `response` object after the HTTP call is done. However, it seems that the result from this function is ignored.